# looking for an attribute (decoration) to mention source property name that works with auto-mapper

Tags: c#, automapper

i have my DTOs that look like this

```
  public class SomeDTO
{
    public string last_name{ get; set; }
    public string account_number { get; set; }
}
```

my property name has underscores because i have to map it to the property names of the source.It works fine.

but i am looking for some attribute that help me to name my DTOs properly. So that i could have something like.

```
   public class SomeDTO
{
    [Something("last_name")]   
    public string LastName{ get; set; }
    [Something("account_number")]   
    public string AccountNumber { get; set; }
}
```

"Column" isn't working because i guess it works with EF Only.

This is the code of generic auto mapping. that maps data-reader to DTO.

```
        public T ExecuteQuerySingle<T>(List<SqlParameter> paramList, string commandString)
    {
        using (var conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConStr"].ConnectionString))

        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(commandString, conn))
        {

                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                foreach (var param in paramList)
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
                }
                conn.Open();
                var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                    T item;
                    Mapper.CreateMap<IDataReader, T>();
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        item = Mapper.Map<IDataReader, T>(reader);
                        return item;
                    }
                    conn.Close();
                    return default(T);
                }
                conn.Close();
                return default(T);

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you could implement `INamingConvention` to convert name to convenient also you could implement logic for reading custom attribute and fill fields manually